# Jquery select dropdowns (array) option on change get value from div class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple select dropdowns and multiple divs with the same class.
Each div have one dropdown and one div with a class .dz-filename.

By uploading an image > filename text come into the div with the class .dz-filename and for that image you can choose a format. I want to link the image with the format, based on the selection.

How can i get the text inside the div with class .dz-filename and fill this text into the option value?

After submitting the form, I want to use php to see which format is linked to which image

For example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".dz-select-system").change(function(){
       var filename = $(".dz-filename span").text();
alert(filename);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="file_upload_container" class="dropzone dz-clickable dz-started dz-max-files-reached">
<div class="upload">
<div class="dz-filename">
<span data-dz-name="">banner.jpg</span>
</div>
<input type="hidden" class="picture_upload" name="picture_upload[]">
<select class="dz-select-system" style="width: 100%;margin-top: 10px;" name="format[]">
 <option selected="" disabled="" value="-1">Selecteer uw formaat</option>
 <option value="{HERE FILENAME IF THIS OPTION IS SELECT BY USER banner.jpg}">100 x 100, Geen, 1</option>
    <option value="{HERE FILENAME IF THIS OPTION IS SELECT BY USER banner.jpg}">80 x 80, Geen, 1</option>
    <option value="{HERE FILENAME IF THIS OPTION IS SELECT BY USER banner.jpg}">50 x 50, Geen, 1</option>
    <option value="{HERE FILENAME IF THIS OPTION IS SELECT BY USER banner.jpg}">70 x 70, Geen, 1</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="upload">
<div class="dz-filename">
<span data-dz-name="">photobanner1.jpg</span>
</div>
<input type="hidden" class="picture_upload" name="picture_upload[]">
<select class="dz-select-system" style="width: 100%;margin-top: 10px;" name="format[]">
<option selected="" disabled="" value="-1">Selecteer uw formaat</option>
 <option value="{HERE FILENAME IF THIS OPTION IS SELECT BY USER photobanner1.jpg}">100 x 100, Geen, 1</option>
    <option value="{HERE FILENAME IF THIS OPTION IS SELECT BY USER photobanner1.jpg}">80 x 80, Geen, 1</option>
    <option value="{HERE FILENAME IF THIS OPTION IS SELECT BY USER photobanner1.jpg}">50 x 50, Geen, 1</option>
    <option value="{HERE FILENAME IF THIS OPTION IS SELECT BY USER photobanner1.jpg}">70 x 70, Geen, 1</option>
</select>
</div></div>
```

Comment: Bind a listener to the file input onchange event, get those options and set the value attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set an handler for the `onchange` event for file input that calls a function to:

- select the span for that input
- update the span text with the selected file name
- update the corresponding select options with the selected file name

Addition: You can make you select a control that sets the value for a different input field
   ...

```
<select class="dz-select-system" style="width: 100%;margin-top: 10px;">
  <option selected="" disabled="" value="-1">Selecteer uw formaat</option>
  <option>100 x 100, Geen, 1</option>
  <option>80 x 80, Geen, 1</option>
  <option>50 x 50, Geen, 1</option>
  <option>70 x 70, Geen, 1</option>
</select>
<input id="fileNameWithFormat"name='fileNameWithFormat[]' type="hidden"> <!-- this will get value based on input from select option-->
...
```

Next, update your Javascript to set the value for the added hidden input. I have used the "::" delimiter here. You can decide to use a comma or anything.

In your PHP, you'll read value from this field and split by the delimiter to get file name and file format.

```
$(".dz-select-system").change(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $parent = $this.parent();
    var fileFormat = $this.val();
    var fileName = $parent.find('.dz-filename span').text();

    $parent.find('#fileNameWithFormat').val(fileName + '::' + fileFormat);
});
```

Comment: Yes, ok that's working for me but the problem i have no idea wich format is link to the image. Because the format is inside the <option>100 x 100</option> and the value is the filename. I think is best to use option array values? <option value="['filename.jpg', '100x100']">100 x 100, Geen, 1</option>

Comment: You should use a value format like `filename.jpg:100x100`

Comment: see here: https://jsfiddle.net/webvision/fxnjk4cb/ it works but all the values changed over the two select options

Comment: Now i get for every select option values from the filename, but there is not linking with the format... so i need the filename en the selected format...I was thinking about value array? that link the value filename with the selected format

Comment: i won't advise you set value to an array. See documentation for [option elemen](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/option). Even so when you do set it to be an array, you will need to parse value into filename and selected format server side or wherever the form is processed. Setting to a string like I recommended also will have you process the option value. However you'll just be splitting by `:`.

Comment: A better idea is to have a hidden `input[name=format]` that is updated with the selected option text whenever it's changed.

Comment: Okay, do you have a example how can do this? I am trying but nothung works

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".dz-select-system").change(function() {
    //$(this).find(".dz-filename span").text();
    //console.log($(this).prev().prev().find("span").text());

    var filename = $(this).prev().prev().find("span").text();
    alert(filename);
//OR var filename = $(this).prevUntil(".dz-filename span").text().trim();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="file_upload_container" class="dropzone dz-clickable dz-started dz-max-files-reached">
  <div class="upload">
    <div class="dz-filename">
      <span data-dz-name="">banner.jpg</span>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" class="picture_upload" name="picture_upload[]">
    <select class="dz-select-system" style="width: 100%;margin-top: 10px;" name="format[]">
      <option selected="" disabled="" value="-1">Selecteer uw formaat</option>
      <option value="{HERE FILENAME IF THIS OPTION IS SELECT BY USER banner.jpg}">100 x 100, Geen, 1</option>
      <option value="{HERE FILENAME IF THIS OPTION IS SELECT BY USER banner.jpg}">80 x 80, Geen, 1</option>
      <option value="{HERE FILENAME IF THIS OPTION IS SELECT BY USER banner.jpg}">50 x 50, Geen, 1</option>
      <option value="{HERE FILENAME IF THIS OPTION IS SELECT BY USER banner.jpg}">70 x 70, Geen, 1</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="upload">
    <div class="dz-filename">
      <span data-dz-name="">photobanner1.jpg</span>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" class="picture_upload" name="picture_upload[]">
    <select class="dz-select-system" style="width: 100%;margin-top: 10px;" name="format[]">
      <option selected="" disabled="" value="-1">Selecteer uw formaat</option>
      <option value="{HERE FILENAME IF THIS OPTION IS SELECT BY USER photobanner1.jpg}">100 x 100, Geen, 1</option>
      <option value="{HERE FILENAME IF THIS OPTION IS SELECT BY USER photobanner1.jpg}">80 x 80, Geen, 1</option>
      <option value="{HERE FILENAME IF THIS OPTION IS SELECT BY USER photobanner1.jpg}">50 x 50, Geen, 1</option>
      <option value="{HERE FILENAME IF THIS OPTION IS SELECT BY USER photobanner1.jpg}">70 x 70, Geen, 1</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```